# Error while creating task: The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again. (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I get the following error while saving a task inside task list:

***"The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again."***

I tried **restarting "search service host controller"**.

The server has **8 GB** RAM and according to task manager, 6.67 GB is being used.

I logged into the site with user which is the owner of the site. I tried creating tasks from client as well as the SharePoint server itself. Same error is shown in both the cases.

How do I find information on the exact problem that is causing the error? What are possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this to be directly related to the Search Host Controller Service. This apparently is gobbling up all the memory on the WFE. Once restarted I can now save the form items. I watched it regress from 8gb (max on this server) to about 6.7gb and suddenly this red error went away.  I plan on doubling the memory to 16gb to try to remove the problem altogether.